# Copying contents of a file located in folders between start and end folders

Tags: python

[image]

> In each folder between the start and end folders there is a single text file and a couple subfolders. I need to copy the contents of all of these text files between the two points into a single text file in another location. There also happen to be many of these intervals in the folder they are held in so they have to be the most recent folders between start and end. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please, show us what have you attempted so far and what issues you run into.

Comment: I don't know what to do, hence why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, and trawl the folders:

```
files = {#your files} 
 
for filename in os.listdir(): 
    if os.path.isfile(filename) and f.endswith(".txt"):
        if not filename in files:
            with open(filename, "r") as file: 
            files[filename] = file.read() 
 
for filename, text in files.items(): 
    # Write contents to your final file.
```